# Laravel 5.2: Inverse (reverse) of seeJson in testing

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-5

I've been using PHPUnit ***4.8*** on Laravel 5.2, wondering if it's possible to see if an API call does NOT have a JSON object in its response.

You can see if the response has a particular object, but how about doing the opposite?

```
$this->json('GET', 'api/items')
        ->seeJson(['id' => "100"])
        ->notSeeJson(['id' => "222"])//Is there anything like it?
        ->assertResponseOk();
```

I've been reading the documentation of PHPUnit and Laravel 5.2, but haven't found how to achieve it.

Any advice will be appreciated.

***PS***

In order to make sure that a particular object isn't included in the response, it'll suffice to count the total number of objects the response has.

With newer versions of PHPUnit, it's possible to do so with `assertJsonCount(2, 'data')`.

But how about PHPUnit4/Laravel5.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to note these are Laravel 5.2 methods, not PHPUnit methods, defined in `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase`.

The inverse of seeJson is dontSeeJson.

```
$this->json('GET', 'api/items')
    ->seeJson(['id' => "100"])
    ->dontSeeJson(['id' => "222"])
    ->assertResponseOk();
```